# fiware-orion -- Install Orion Context Broker 4.3.2 (ReleaseName) / 0.22.0 (Version) on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: deb, undefined-symbol, fiware-orion, ubuntu-15.04

I am willing to install the latest release of Orion Context Broker (ReleaseName: 4.3.2 / Version: 0.22.0) from https://forge.fiware.org/frs/?group_id=7#title_data-orioncontextbroker on Ubuntu 15.04..

I did some research on this issue already. To be precise it became a longer description. If that's to much text just **reading the bold parts will** probably **do**.

I managed the absence of a native .deb-package (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463012/fiware-orion-context-broker-on-ubuntu)) by using converting (alien --scripts contextBroker-0.22.0-1.x86_64.rpm ) the existing .rpm-package.

After relinking several libraries (ln -s libboost_XZY-mt.so.5 libboost_XZY.so) and trying to start contextBroker I got this

**Error Message:**
**contextBroker: symbol lookup error: contextBroker: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6detail17once_global_epochE**

It [turned out](http://upstream-tracker.org/compat_reports/boost/1.34.1_to_1.35.0/abi_compat_report.html) due to the change from version 1.34.1 to 1.35.0 of the boost-libs this symbol (function call) was deleted. **(!) That was in 2011 (!)**.

This lib (1.35.0) is so old it is not even longer available from [Ubuntu repositories](http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boost1.35/) (it is just an empty directory). These days (01 Jun 2015) we deal with libboost_*.so.1.55.0. Even if I would want to I can't install this deprecated lib.

**Is it correct that the latest release of Orion Context Broker (0.22.0) which is dated 2015-05-25 needs a deprecated lib from 2011 ?**

Can you please provide a .deb-package compiled/linked to up to date libs.

Except of compiling src on my own (-> lots of make issues) or installing a 2011 ubuntu - what can I do to fix that (undefined symbol) problem?

Any help is appreciated
GP

Answer (score 1):

With version 1.41 of boost libs it should work. At least it does in 0.21.

Comment: Where did you get 1.41 from?  
  
Neither at de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ nor at archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ (these are all repositories listed in /etc/apt/sources.list) is this version (1.41) available.  
  
Both repositories just offer 1.40 or 1.42.  with 1.42 empty.
  
So I dared to install [http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/boost1.40/](libboost1.40-dev_1.40.0-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb).  
  
I ended up with this error:  
  **Depenency is not satisfiable: libicu42 (>=4.2-1)**  
  
Any ideas how I can fix that?

Comment: You have to look for CentOS libboost version and install  the rpm files with alien.

Comment: Any suggestions | tips | ideas | experiences which version of CentOS to choose from http://mirror.centos.org/centos/ and | or in which subdir to find libboost_1.41?