# How do I create the fiware-orion deb package?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

My project used a Raspberry Pi3 with Debian OS and in it I execute the fiware-orion. I have compiled the Orion source code for the architecture arm64 (aarch64). Now I need to create the fiware-orion deb package.

The documentation only explains how to build the rpm package with rpm-build.

I did a search and that's all I found:
 [Fiware Orion context Broker on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463012/fiware-orion-context-broker-on-ubuntu/28473138#28473138)

Is it possible to create the fiware-orion deb package?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be possible. However, as far as I know, nobody has do that yet :)

As said in the question post you cite:

> FIWARE Orion is a open source community driver project, so if you want to contribute in that sense [to create a .deb package], don't hesitate to propose the needed changes to the repository (as pull requests).

This [document](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/packaging-tutorial/packaging-tutorial.en.pdf) seems to be a good starting point.